# Is there any downfall in importing a whole library in java

Tags: java, import

Is there a downside to doing this:

```
import java.util.*;
```

rather than importing a specific part:

```
import java.util.Stack;
```

Does it take more time to build for example?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't feel the difference, **but** for the sake of clear and readable code you should import only the classes you actially need.

Comment: *You wouldn't feel the difference* because the compile will replace `import foo.bar.*` by `import foo.bar.NeededClass1; import foo.bar.NeededClass2; import foo.bar.NeededInterfaceX;` and on for you, but I consider it is a bad practice, even more when IDEs already have a function to complete this for you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Some people consider .* as a bad practice since it is less readable and does not allow you to understand the class' relationships with other types just by looking at imports.